# Ruby on Rails: Show picture in html in html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need a draggable picture on my Ruby on Rails- Website and everything is working fine, except the picture does not show up.

This is the code for the picture with its properties:

```
<img id="drag1" src="/images/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

If I write this, the picture does show up:

```
<%= image_tag("img_logo.gif") %>
```

My question: What do I need to insert in the upper code, so my picture (img_logo.gif) does show up?

The picture itself is located in: /app/assets/images/img_logo.gif

The file, in which this code is written is a html.erb file.

I haven't installed any gems like paperclip or imagemagick.

Edit: Thanks to Meagar and Vic, this will work:

Either this:

```
<%= image_tag('img_logo.gif', draggable: "true", id: "drag1") %>
```

OR this:

```
<img id="drag1" src="<%= asset_path('img_logo.gif') %>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: Please seem my updated answer. The solution you have chosen is incorrect, and will fail when you try to deploy your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `<img id="drag1" src="/images/img_logo.gif"` is working, then the image is *not* in your asset pipeline, it's in `public/images`.

If the image *were* in your asset pipeline, at `app/assets/images/img_logo.gif`, then the correct URL for it would be `/assets/img_logo.gif`.

The code you have, `image_tag("img_logo.gif")` **is correct**, as it will output the correct URL `/assets/img_logo.gif`, assuming the image is where you say it is, and you haven't changed any settings regarding the asset pipeline. The fact that you're successfully able to request the image using `/images/img_logo.gif` tells me that this isn't the case, and you  haven't accurately described your situation.

---

#### Regarding Your comment:

> Thanks for your answer: It works, when I typed this in: `<img id="drag1" src="/assets/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">`

**Don't do that**.

I think you communicated *backwards* what was happening. I understood that `<img src="/images/img_logo.gif"` was *working*, and that `image_tag` was failing. I now see that `image_tag` was working all along, but you were trying to figure out how to supply extra attributes (`id="drag1" draggable=true` etc) to the `<img>` tag being output.

You cannot hardcode asset paths like that. It will work in development, but the asset URL is *different in production*, and your site will stop working.

To achieve what you're after, you can either pass attributes to your `image_tag` helper, or you can use `asset_path` in your HTML tag:

Either this...

```
<%= image_tag('img_logo.gif', draggable: "true", id: "drag1") %>
```

OR this...

```
<img id="drag1" src="<%= asset_path('img_logo.gif') %>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

But **do not use this**:

```
<img id="drag1" src="/assets/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: It works, when I typed this in: <img id="drag1" src="/assets/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

Comment: @NadjaKuhn That is **wrong**. You cannot hard-code asset paths like this, or it will fail in production!

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem and I understand much better now! I can't upvote your answer, because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

With `<%= image_tag("img_logo.gif") %>` being used and the image showing up, right click on the image in your website, and click 'inspect element'. You should see that the src is different from `'/images/img_logo.gif'`. It should have some gibberish.

If it is, the reason is because of how rails handles its assets. Check out [this rails guide on fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) for more detailed explanation on the rationale of implementing this.

If its not, do share what it is.

Lastly, the production site is not able to access the `app/assets` folder. It can only access the files and subdirectories in the `public` folder. You can try putting the gif file in `/public/images/img_logo.gif` and it should appear with your first code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: It works, when I typed this in: <img id="drag1" src="/assets/img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">